# jsoup exception invalid url

Tags: java, jsoup

Recently, I'm trying to use jsoup to parse web page. I have this piece of code to connect to url:

```
page.url = "https://admin.xosn.com/pdf9/3876515.pdf?DB_OEM_ID=31000";
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(page.url);
Document htmlDocument = conn.get();
this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
if(!conn.response().contentType().contains("text/html")) {
    System.out.println("**Failure**\nRetrieved something other than  HTML");
    return false;
}
```

and I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:74)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:38)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
```

It seems to work in browser. I don't know why it does not work with jsoup.

Comment: What is line 102 of Validate.java checking? Or line 74 of HttpConnection.java?

Comment: Your url works fine for me. Please [edit] your question and provide short but full example which will let us reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is HTML Parser, it cannot parse Pdf, you can verify your url before parsing it in jsoup by using HttpUrlConnection

```
String url4e = "https://admin.xosn.com/pdf9/3876515.pdf?DB_OEM_ID=31000";
URL url1 = new URL(url4e);   
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.connect();
System.out.println(conn.getContentType());
```

Comment: Yes, I found out. I can make it work with 'ignorecontenttype'. Thanks.